# Accessing Server Variables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, google-analytics

I have a web form that is used to order different products. The logic (DB connection etc.) behind the form is written in PHP. Now I want to track the submitted forms as events via Google Analytics.

There is only one form where a visitor can choose the products to order via checkboxes. Since this is variable, I cannot simply call the GA-function with an onClick-Event. My solution was to write the active checkboxes to $_POST['order'] and then pull that data via JavaScript to fill the parameters for the function `ga('send', 'event',...)`, like this: `var ordertype = <?php echo $_POST['order']; ?>;`

While this **does** work, whenever the page is opened without the Post-Data filled yet, my JS looks like `var ordertype = ;`, which does produce an error on the console (of course). Using something like `var ordertype = <?php echo if(isset( $_POST['order']); ?>;` isn't working either, since that doesn't output anything.

Any thoughts on how I can do this more elegantly?

Comment: `var ordertype = "<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['order']); ?>";`
then later `if (ordertype ) ga('send', 'event',...),...` - you do need to clean your data or people can inject stuff

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't think of that!

Comment: For cleaning data you might also want to look at the filter functions in PHP (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `var ordertype =` inside your echo:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['order'])){
    echo 'var ordertype = ' . $_POST['order'] . ';'
}?>
```

That way, `ordertype` will not be defined at all if `$_POST['order']` is not set. If you want it to be set to a different value, just add an `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use this workaround:

`var ordertype = ''+<?php echo if(isset( $_POST['order']); ?>;`

With this, if the post value is not present, the variable `ordertype` will be empty string and later on, you can assign an updated value to it as it has already been declared above.

Comment: that would result in `var ordertype = ''+someorder;` that is not valid JS unless ordertype is numric